# Can I create an app where the user never has to log in or create a username and password?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using firebase/firestore and I really don't want or need anyone to sign in or create a user ID.   I have one collection that I'd like the user to write to.  The fields are meaningless and have no information that would mean anything to anyone but reports I would like to have.  All of the other collections are read only.  Will I be allowed to do this as far as firebase and Apple publishing the app?  If necessary could I create a user with device name and a password but the user would not have to do anything or ever have to?

Comment: Sure, you can build whatever you want. But you should review the guidelines for the stores you intend to publish to.  We can't give you advice about that.

Comment: will firebase have an issue with allowing anyone that has the app to write to a collection with no authentication whatsoever?   I'm just testing and I get warnings about my auth. rules everyday

Comment: Sure, you can build whatever you want.  You assume the cost of any security risks in your implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I'll noodle with it but sounds like I can allow the user to write to the one collection and everything else will be read only.  Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using Firebase/Firestore and I really don't want or need anyone to sign in or create a user ID.

There is no requirement that says that you should implement Firebase Authentication to create an app or to write some data to Firestore. It's up to you to decide if you implement it or not. There is nothing to force you to implement authentication, if you don't have to.

> I have one collection that I'd like the user to write to. The fields are meaningless and have no information that would mean anything to anyone but reports I would like to have them. All of the other collections are read-only.

If you only need to have a single collection in which the user can write, then allow the users in security rules to only write to that collection and restrict all the other ones.

> Will I be allowed to do this as far as Firebase and Apple publishing the app?

When you publish an app, there is no constraint regarding authentication. You can publish an app that doesn't have authentication.

> If necessary could I create a user with a device name and a password but the user would not have to do anything or ever have to?

As @DougStevenson already mentioned in his comment, you can do whatever you want, even implement your own authenticator mechanism, but I'm not sure why would you do that.

In the end, please don't forget to read the document regarding [security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), because malicious users might take advantage of unsecured databases. When it comes to Firestore, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.